# Problem in Appending dictionary to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe(`User` is the index)(Also, this a part of a bigger dataframe, so `Series` cannot be used):

```
User  Score
A         5
B        10
A         4
C         8
```

I want to add `Score` of duplicate `User`s.

So First I calculate the Sum of `Score` of the duplicate `User`:

```py
sum = df.loc['A'].sum()
```

Then I drop the duplicate rows:

```py
df.drop('A',inplace=True)
```

Then I append the new values as a dictionary to the dataframe:

```py
dic = {'User':'A','Score':10}
df = df.append(dic,ignore_index=True)
```

But I get this dataframe:

```
   Score User
0     10  NaN
1      8  NaN
2     10    A
```

The default autoincrement values has replaced `User` as index and values of `User` are non `NaN`.
The expected dataframe would be:

```
User  Score
B        10
C         8
A         9
```

Comment: try:  ```df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dic),ignore_index=True)```

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod Got this error : `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting will not work because your original dataframe has an Index called 'User', not a column. You're trying to append a dict, defining a column called 'User', with a DataFrame that has no such column.

Compare the result of your

```
df = df.append(dic,ignore_index=True)
with
df = df.reset_index().append(dic,ignore_index=True)
```

However, this begs the question of why you're doing it this way. What you want to do can be simply achieved with a groupby, a la

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'User': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'Score': [5, 10, 4, 8]}
data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Out[6]: 
  User  Score
0    A      5
1    B     10
2    A      4
3    C      8
df.set_index('User')
Out[7]: 
      Score
User       
A         5
B        10
A         4
C         8
df = df.set_index('User')
df
Out[10]: 
      Score
User       
A         5
B        10
A         4
C         8
df.groupby('User').sum()
Out[30]: 
      Score
User       
A         9
B        10
C         8
```

Comment: Thanks. Was unaware of the `groupby` method. Just checked the docs, can be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Let's say you have the below dataframe

```
df
```

[image]

you can use the below code to get the result

```
df.groupby('User')['Score'].sum().reset_index().set_index('User')
```

[image]